# Energy in an electron/positron electric field shortly after pair production

Tags: electrostatics, energy-conservation, pair-production

Just a quick thought, I was considering the energy contained within the electric field and was curious about the following situation:

Consider you create an electron/positron pair (using a third body as is required of course). Considering that the electric field of the two (a dipole field mostly) would spread outward at the speed of light, one would have that the energy of the system is continually increasing as the field spreads out over space. Where does this come from? I get that I'm ignoring full quantum field effects and that is probably the answer to this. Don't be afraid to dive into the math for an answer.

I'm sure it's simple and I'm just missing it.

**EDIT**
From another perspective (more in the context of QED), one could ask about the self energy (due to the electric field) of an electron/positron pair. The question in this case would be is there a time dependence on the mass/energy renormalization that quickly approaches (after pair production and as the field spreads out in space) the value we take for constant?

Comment: "I'm ignoring full quantum field effects. Don't be afraid to dive into the math" and "I'm sure it's simple and I'm just missing it" are mutually exclusive.